# How to add default tokens to TokenAutoComplete using addObject(obj) method call in Android

Tags: android, token, android-chips

How to add default tokens to `TokenAutoComplete` using `addObject(obj)` method call in Android.

I tried using the `addObject` method but it behaves very differently a from what I expected, so please, help me to get a solution for this.

I want to add tokens like `All`, `Subordinates` in the `TokenAutoComplete` box before a user can search and add token from the search list

Comment: Are we talking about this library? https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete What does happen when you use the `addObject()` method?

Comment: yes I am talking about the same library, and the addObject method is not working as expected.

Comment: have you tried the overload `addObject(obj,String)`? And since it's open source, you could try to step into the code to see what happens.

Comment: yes thanks for your comments, I have been trying to dig into the code...

Answer (score 0):

addObject should put the token in the list. When you call addObject what happens? The only thing that's tricky about addObject is that I have to delay actually adding the object until the next UI thread update.